# neccesary conditions for quotient maps

Tags: general-topology

By definition, $p: X \to Y$ is quotient map if it is surjective and holds$ V \subseteq Y$ open $\iff p^{-1}(V) \subseteq X$ open. Now, not every quotient map must be open, however, i can not see why this argument fails:

Let $p: X \to Y$ continuos and surjective. By continuity  $  V \subseteq Y$ open $\implies p^{-1}(V) \subseteq X$ open. Since $p( p^{-1}(V)) \subseteq V$ and $p$ is surjective,it holds $p( p^{-1}(V)) = V$. Then we have $ p^{-1}(V) \subseteq X$ open $\implies  V \subseteq Y$ open. But this implication says that $p$ is open map. Moreover, we can conclude that for being a quotient map is enough continuity and surjectivity.

I'm almost sure i'm missing something because this makes no sense for me, so what would it be, please help me

Comment: Where does your "Then we have $ p^{-1}(V) \subseteq X$ open $\implies  V \subseteq Y$ open" come from?

Comment: because $V=p( p^{-1}(V))\subseteq p(X)=Y$ but i see now V doesn't have to be open. However, assuming V is open, this characterization of quotient maps implies being an open map, why this still makes no sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You prove that if $U=p^{-1}(V)$ with $V\subseteq Y$ open, then $p(U)$ is open. However, not all open of $X$ is the form $p^{-1}(V)$, with $V$ open of $Y$.